# SAP B1 Query Returns "Must declare scalar variable " error

Tags: sql, sapb1

I am attempting to create a drop down menu which will limit the query results by item buyer with the following SQL code. However, I keep getting an error stating that I need to declare the scalar variable @ItemBuyer, despite the fact that it is clearly declared and set in the code.

```
    DECLARE @ItemBuyer VARCHAR(30)
    SET @ItemBuyer= /* T3.OwnerCode */ '[%1]'

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)  
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT T3.[DocNum] AS DocNumber, T3.[CardCode] AS 
    VendorCode, T3.[CardName] AS VendorName, T3.OwnerCode as BuyerID, T2.
    [ItemCode] AS ItemNo, T2.[U_CPM_LegItemNo] AS LegacyItemNumber, T2.
    [Dscription] AS ItemDescription, T2.[U_CPM_ConfDate] AS POConfirmDate, 
    T2.[OpenCreQty] AS CreditMemoAmount FROM  [dbo].[OITG] T0 ,  [dbo].
    [OITM] T1  INNER  JOIN [dbo].[POR1] T2  ON  T2.[ItemCode] = T1.
    [ItemCode]   INNER  JOIN [dbo].[OPOR] T3  ON  T3.[DocEntry] = T2.
    [DocEntry]   WHERE (T2.[OpenCreQty] > (0 ) ) AND  (T2.[U_CPM_ConfDate] 
    IS NULL  ) and (T3.[OwnerCode] = @ItemBuyer)'

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

I also tried declaring and setting the variable like below:

```
    DECLARE @ItemBuyer VARCHAR(30) = /* T3.[OwnerCode] */ '[%0]'
```

But then I get an error stating that the syntax is wrong, even through the variable now returns the correct value. Im a little stuck here. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks,

Krys

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql?

Comment: You are using the dynamic query and you are not providing value for your dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
/*SELECT FROM [dbo].[OPOR] P1*/
declare @ItemBuyer as int
/* WHERE */
set @ItemBuyer = /* P1.OwnerCode */ '[%0]'


SELECT T3.[DocNum] AS DocNumber
, T3.[CardCode] AS VendorCode
, T3.[CardName] AS VendorName
, T3.OwnerCode as BuyerID
, T2.[ItemCode] AS ItemNo
, T2.[U_CPM_LegItemNo] AS LegacyItemNumber
, T2.[Dscription] AS ItemDescription
, T2.[U_CPM_ConfDate] AS POConfirmDate
, T2.[OpenCreQty] AS CreditMemoAmount 
FROM [dbo].[POR1] T2  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OPOR] T3 ON T3.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry]
WHERE T2.[OpenCreQty] > 0 
AND T2.[U_CPM_ConfDate] IS NULL 
and T3.[OwnerCode] = @ItemBuyer
```

I still can't manage to remember the dynamic syntax query, so I have to use this link every single time I want to do it: http://www.clientsfirst-us.com/blog/sap/sap-business-one/user-defined-prompts-in-sap-business-one-queries/

Notice, also, that I got rid of a couple tables that you weren't using in your `select` or your `where` statements. It's probably not going to make THAT big of a difference in the query speed, but it just makes it cleaner. (I also cleaned up the formatting to put it in my favorite style, but that's not strictly necessary)